# Windows 10 Installer Won't Work

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation, microsoft

I have run into an issue that is beyond my capability to resolve, and therefore I have come to ask for help.

I am not able to install or uninstall any apps/software on my laptop. All it does is hang, making me want to do backflips, but I'm a bit front-heavy so I can't, super annoying.

What I have done to resolve the matter:

- When I run `netfxrepairtool`, I get this message;

```
 Reregister Windows Installer service
Unregisters and re-registers the Windows Installer service using MsiExec.exe. Applicable regardless of the diagnosis results.

 Restart Windows Installer service
Stops and restarts the Windows Installer service. Applicable regardless of the diagnosis results.
```

- When I click next, it says:

```
Changes complete, please try reinstalling the .NET Framework.
```

- When I click next, I see a window saying:

```
 Submit additional information. This tool is unable to resolve the installation on your computer and allows me to download a log as a Cabinet File and shows the following.

C:\Windows\logs\cbs\cbs.log

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\FixDotNet.log

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\NetFxSetupEvents.txt

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_netfxrepairtool_decompression_log.txt

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\FixDotNet_HKCR_Installer.regdump

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\FixDotNet_HKLM_Installer.regdump
```

- Reinstalling the .NET Framework: I ran Command Prompt `SFC /SCANNOW` and got the following message:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. 
For offline repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.
```

I spend some time with Microsoft support they elevated my ticket to level 2, where we ended up installing Windows 10 again, (MediaCreationTool22H2). This ran and then I got to the point where it said looking for updates, and got stuck at 2% update for 8 hours, it was late so I went to bed and when I got up it was still at 2%.

From there I shut the computer down and restarted.

Then I download Windows10Upgrade9252, and it said that I am up to date.

Still, I am not able to install or uninstall any software.

What can I do?

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Have there been any hardware changes to the latop recently, such as new RAM?

Comment: Yes, a short while ago I sent my laptop to change my hard drive.

Comment: .NET Framework 4.8 CANNOT be reinstalled. The installer your attempting to use cannot be used to resolve your current issue. If the system corruption is so bad, you cannot install Windows 22H2 and perform an in-place install, then your only option is a clean installation of Windows by booting to a Windows installation media

Comment: @Ramhound would I need to make a backup of my files and folder before I do a clean install? My question is will it wipe all current data?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to do a rest from my local drive and everything is working perfectly again. 

Thanks to everyone who offered guidance, I knew my issue would find a solution when I posted here. Stay blessed.